# Thermal Printer PHP (Mike42 Classes)

Tags: php, networking, character-encoding, thermal-printer

I'm trying to use Mike42 Classes Library, already connected to the printer and everything works fine.
then I'm trying to print hebrew letters and Getting "?????" or Some Gibberish Strings.

Anyone already tried also?

Comment: _“Anyone already tried also?”_ - that is not a proper way to ask a question here on this site. Please go read [ask].

Comment: This article may be helpful. [HS-589C Hebrew output #246](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/246)